# laravel4 authentication method

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have my own user table and the password use other encryption methods. Now I want to use laravel 4 and my existing user table to do some other applications.How can I authentication in laravel 4.In other words, how can I use other authentication method in laravel4 instead of hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This an example of authentication using md5():

```
$user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

if( $user && $user->password == md5(Input::get('password')) )
{
    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```